# A mysql query to fill a table with data aggregated from a source table

Tags: mysql

I want to fill some fields of a table (freq) with aggregated data from fields of another table (tbl1). I did this with a query I prepare from scratch every time I have to update a new field.
You can see the tables and query details in the  code I submit. N field value is limited from 1 to 10, you can see the routine by which I create it. To the same value are also limited the values coming from tbl1. I wonder if it's possible to obtain same results without cycling, with a single, more effective query that I'm not able to imagine...

```
    /*---- tbl1 ---*/

    1,id,db2020,tbl1,SMALLINT UNSIGNED,binary,5,3,0 /* same as latter table, used to avoid */ 
    2,Data,db2020,tbl1,DATE,binary,10,10,0          /* accidental data corruption of the same table */
    3,id2,db2020,tbl1,TINYINT UNSIGNED,binary,3,3,0
    4,fld1,db2020,tbl1,TINYINT UNSIGNED,binary,3,2,0
    5,fld2,db2020,tbl1,TINYINT UNSIGNED,binary,3,2,0
    6,fld3,db2020,tbl1,TINYINT UNSIGNED,binary,3,2,0

    /*--- freq ---*/                    /* here aggregated data from tbl1 go to the corrensponding fields */

    1,N,db2020,freq,TINYINT UNSIGNED,binary,2,0,0   /* primary key, it's also the set of all possible values in the fields of tbl1*/
    2,fld1,db2020,freq,SMALLINT UNSIGNED,binary,4,0,0 /* the frequency of the N value in tbl1.fld1 */
    3,fld2,db2020,freq,SMALLINT UNSIGNED,binary,4,0,0 /* the frequency of the N value in tbl1.fld2 */
    4,fld3,db2020,freq,SMALLINT UNSIGNED,binary,5,0,0 /* the frequency of the N value in tbl1.fld3 */
    5,Tins,db2020,freq,INT UNSIGNED,binary,6,0,0      /* the sum of the values in fld1, fld2, fld3 */


    CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `fill_index`() /* to fill freq N field when the table is just created or empty */
    BEGIN
   DECLARE a INT Default 1 ;
    simple_loop: LOOP         
       insert into freq(N) values(a);
       SET a=a+1;
        IF a=11 THEN /* 10 is the max value for N */
           LEAVE simple_loop;
     END IF;
   END LOOP simple_loop;
END

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `freq_count`() /* aggregates tbl1 field values to freq table */
BEGIN                                              /* it works, but i'd like to find  something better */
DECLARE i INT Default 0;                           /* with no need to cycle for every new field, it looks slow */
DECLARE f_name text(3);
DECLARE comando text(250);
DECLARE astring text(10);
    fname_loop: LOOP         
       SET i=i+1;
       IF i= 4 THEN
          LEAVE fname_loop;
       END IF;
       CASE
        WHEN i = 1 THEN SET f_name = 'fld1';
        WHEN i = 2 THEN SET f_name = 'fld2';    
        WHEN i = 3 THEN SET f_name = 'fld3';
       END CASE;
       IF (i < 4)  THEN
         SET @comando = CONCAT('UPDATE freq, (select ',f_name,
         ', count(',f_name,') as tot',f_name,
         ' from tbl1 group by ',f_name,') as t2 ',
         'SET freq.',f_name,' = t2.tot',f_name,
         ' WHERE  freq.N = t2.',f_name,';');
        
    /*           select @comando;  */
         PREPARE stmt1 FROM @comando;
         EXECUTE stmt1;
       
       END IF;



     END LOOP;

END
```

Moreover, if you look to freq table, you'll see Tins field. This field should be filled with the sum of the fields in the same row, and possibly in  the same operation that updates all other fields. I have tried the following separate query, but it doesn't work for more than a single line, and instead fills Tins with wrong values, maybe because I wasn't able to find a way to zero the 'total' variable among rows.

```
    CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `sum_totals`() /* this would fill the Tins field */
    BEGIN                                                      /* but works badly, only for a single row */
     DECLARE i INT default 1;                                  /* when in the loop fills Tins with wrong values */
     DECLARE total INT default 0;                              /* it looks that total isn't cleared after the end of a cycle */
     simple_loop: LOOP                                         /* and anyway it tooks a lot of time */
     set total = 0;
     UPDATE freq, (SELECT( if(fld1,fld1,0) + if(fld2,fld2,0) + if(fld3,fld3,0)) AS total
        FROM freq WHERE N = i) AS t2 
        SET freq.Tins = t2.total WHERE N = i;           /* whithout the double where  it definitely doesn't work a single time...*/
        SET i= i+1; 
        IF i=11 THEN
         LEAVE simple_loop;
        END IF;
       END LOOP simple_loop;       

   END
```

Can you please help me?

Kind regards

UPDATE:
I succeeded in refining the last procedure 'sum totals'
Now it works well:

```
            /* a better approach to filling a summed field without need for loops*/
            
     CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `sum_totals`()
    BEGIN
     UPDATE freq,
     (SELECT( if(fld_1,fld_1,0) + if(fld_2,fld_2,0) + if(fld_3,fld_3,0)) /* if is to translate NULLs in zeroes in sum */
      AS total, N AS N1
     FROM freq
     WHERE N > 0) AS t2
     SET freq.Tins = t2.total, 
     WHERE freq.N = t2.N1;    

    END
```

That in the hope it can turn useful to someone else.

UPDATE 1:
I same way succeeded in better coding the 'fill index' procedure.
Here's my code:

```
      /*---- a brute-force method to fill  an index in a new or truncated table  ----*/
      /*  should be refined using a variable to create the values list, but presently I didn't succeed */
     /* in creating such a variable that 'values' syntax doesn't reject. A string doesn't work. */

     CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `fill_indice`()
     BEGIN
       insert into freq(N) values (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10)
     END

    /*----                  index fill end              ----*/
    /*---- a better solution  to automatically fill an index field in a new or truncated table ---*/
   CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `fill_indice`()
   BEGIN
    declare cmd varchar(500);
    declare stp INT default 91;
    declare cntr int default 1;
    set @cmd = 'insert into freq(N) values ';
    while cntr < stp DO
        if ((stp - cntr) > 1) then  
            set @cmd = CONCAT(@cmd, '(',cntr,'),');
        else
            set @cmd = CONCAT(@cmd, '(',cntr,')'); /* this is to avoid the last comma, after the last row value */
        end if;
       set cntr = cntr + 1;
    end while;
    /*select @cmd;*/

  PREPARE stmt1 FROM @cmd;
  EXECUTE stmt1;

 END

 /*----                        better fill end                        ----*/
```

and, presently, that's all... folks! ;-)